# echo "<img src=".$file." >" ; doesn't display image

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<img src=".$file." >" ;
```

does not display image, while $file points to the correct image location C:\wamp\www\formulae\public\images\13.png

part of code reads as follows

```
$file = LIBPATH.DS.'images'.DS.$id.'.png' ;
if(file_exists($file)){
echo $file."</br>";
echo "<img src='".$file."' >" ;

}
```

Comment: if it says "C:\wamp..." then unless you are viewing the page on a machine with that file there, it wont work. more likely you want the $file variable to contain "\public\images\13.png"

Comment: yes I am checking it on the same machine, I am pointing to the absolute path

Comment: while code reads $file = LIBPATH.DS.'images'.DS.$id.'.png' ;
if(file_exists($file)){
echo $file."</br>";
echo "<img src='".$file."' >" ;

}

Comment: Does no PHP tutorial on the planet teach variable interpolation?

Comment: From your browser when you look at the generated HTML, what do you see?

Comment: Quentin I appreciate if you could help me with this, echo $file was just to check that it is pointing to correct image

Comment: @bugfinder this is what I see <html>
<body>
This is another test formulaC:\wamp\www\formulae\public\images\13.png</br><img src=C:\wamp\www\formulae\public\images\13.png >
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Pradeep — @Fabrizio D. gave a perfectly fine answer. Use URIs, don't use file paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo file_dir . '/' . $imageone; ?>" height="100" width="100"/>
```

would help you

Comment: @Pradeep: Then you should not have accepted this answer. If it did help, delete your comment.

Comment: yes it did help. You just neet to adapt it to your code. Maybe you can hire him to do so....

Comment: how can  i display image instead of displaying image path name, https://docs.google.com/document/d/18-IQYbNxaVcOkU1B_qLTviKViUjgfos6DA6rw8taX_g/edit

Comment: Old question / answer but still very useful. Helped me solve a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

You should use paths relative to your Apache document root and not absolute to your file system.

Comment: Indeed. The src attribute takes a URI, not a Windows style file path.

Comment: It should do. You probably got the path wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
```

Comment: how can  i display image instead of displaying image path name, https://docs.google.com/document/d/18-IQYbNxaVcOkU1B_qLTviKViUjgfos6DA6rw8taX_g/edit

Comment: It will display image, not the path as it is within the <img> tag